# Can anyone explain how primitive roots work?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Right now I'm studying out of Audrey Terras' book *Fourier Analysis on Finite Groups and Applications* and we're on the section where we're talking about $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ and when this group is cyclic. I understand that when $n=2,4,p,p^e,2p^e$, then $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic (where $p$ is an odd prime and $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is the multiplicative group mod n such that it has an inverse).

Really my ultimate goal is to show that the sum of all primitive roots mod p add up to the Mobius function $\mu(p-1)\bmod p$, but I can't wrap my head around the connection between cyclic groups and the primitive roots. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Notation. By $(Z/Zn)^*$ do you mean multiplication mod $n$ on $\{k: 1\leq k<n \land \gcd (k,n)=1\}$ ? And by $p$ do you mean an odd prime?

Comment: Yes and yes. I'm sorry I should've specified that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For prime $p$ : A primitive root mod $p$  is any $x$ with $1\leq x<p$ such that the least positive integer $n$ for which $x^n\equiv 1\pmod p$ is $n=p-1.$ Let $G$ be the group $G=(Z/Zp)^*=\{1,...,p-1\}$ with multiplication mod $p.$  Then $x$ is a primitive root mod $p$ iff $x$ is a generator for $G.$ That is, in $G$ we have $\{x^n :0\leq n<p\}=G.$ If $x$ is a primitive root mod $p$ then the set of all primitive roots can be represented in $G$ (that is, reduced mod $p$) as $\{x^n :1\leq n<p \land \gcd (n,p-1)=1\}$. A finite  group $H$ with $|H|$ members is defined to be cylic iff  some $x\in H$ is a generator for $H$, that is $H=\{x^n :1\leq n\leq |H|\}$. The existence of a primitive root mod $p$ is a special case of the following with $F=Z/Zp$.
Lemma:  If $F$ is a finite field then the multiplicative group $G=F\backslash \{0\}$ is cyclic.

Comment: This is a naive question, why can x not be equal to the prime for your first definition of a primitive root? Also, why is that lemma true? Oh, and would you happen to have any hints toward me proving that the sum of all these primitive roots mod p gets me the mobius of p-1 mod p? Thanks for the help.

Comment: If $p$ is prime and $x$ is a primitive root mod  $p$ then $\ne p$ because $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p.$  Example. $(3,3^2,3^3,3^4,3^5,3^6 )$ mod $7$ is  $(3,2,6,4,5,1)$  so $3$ is a primitive root mod $ 7$. The lemma is elementary, but in several steps . You should post it as a Q. You're likely to get a quick A.   As for the sum problem, I dk. I think you should post it as a separate Q to get some attention.

Comment: OK. Seeing those results above definitely helps. Thank you!